# Bazel: wrong syntax addressing headers?

Tags: c, build, bazel

I got a problem with header files not being found even tho they are declared. My rules are generated as stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52539864/10412860) but in execution i get errors that some targets can't find header files they depend on.

```
This is my folder structure:
component1/...        /.../module1/(containing .c and .h files)
          /...        /.../module2/(containing .c and .h files)
          /BUILD.bazel
          /SrcList.bzl
          /macro.bzl
```

The BUILD-file looks like this.

```
cc_library(
  name = "module1",
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
  deps = [],
  srcs = ["//components/module1:target/src/module1.c"],
  linkstatic = True,
  hdrs = ["//components/module1:target/src/module1_1.h", "//components/module1:target/src/module1_2.h", "//components/module1:target/src/module1_3.h"],
)

cc_library(
  name = "module2",
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
  deps = [:module1],
  srcs = ["//components/module2:target/src/module2.c"],
  linkstatic = True,
  hdrs = ["//components/module2:target/src/module2_1.h", "//components/module2:target/src/module2_2.h", "//components/module2:target/src/module2_3.h"],
)
```

Src files are using #include "foo.h" structure. Module2 depends on module1. But if i start the build rule module2 can't find the headers of module1. How do i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Are these targets not under the workspace root?

If that's the case, you will need to root your header files based on the workspace root. 
See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/examples/cpp/hello-lib.cc as an example. Note the include:

`#include "examples/cpp/hello-lib.h"`